# Qual o problema nesta query? Not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql, magento

Me deparei com um problema:

## 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'catalog_product_entity_decimal'

```
SELECT DISTINCT catalog_product_entity.entity_id, sku, price as preco, qty as quantidade, stock_status as estoque, catalog_product_entity_decimal.value as embutido_regra_promo, catalog_product_entity_decimal.value as embutido FROM catalog_product_entity 
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_status ON (cataloginventory_stock_status.product_id = entity_id)
INNER JOIN catalog_product_index_price ON (catalog_product_index_price.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id)
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal ON (catalog_product_entity_decimal.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id AND catalog_product_entity_decimal.attribute_id=249)
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal ON (catalog_product_entity_decimal.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id AND catalog_product_entity_decimal.attribute_id=251)
```

A questão é que os dois ultimos INNERS utilizam a mesma tabela e coluna, porém com atributos diferentes no select, um defini para trazer o resultado do attribute_id 251 e o outro 249.

Alguma solução?

**RESOLUÇÃO:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT c0.entity_id, sku, price as preco, qty as quantidade, stock_status as estoque, c3.value as embutido_regra_promo, c4.value as embutido FROM catalog_product_entity c0 INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_status c1 ON (c1.product_id = c0.entity_id) INNER JOIN catalog_product_index_price c2 ON (c2.entity_id = c0.entity_id) INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal c3 ON (c3.entity_id = c0.entity_id AND c3.attribute_id=249) INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal c4 ON (c4.entity_id = c0.entity_id AND c4.attribute_id=251)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você não está usando aliás para os joins. Tente assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT catalog_product_entity.entity_id, sku, price as preco, qty as quantidade, stock_status as estoque, catalog_product_entity_decimal.value as embutido_regra_promo, catalog_product_entity_decimal.value as embutido 
FROM catalog_product_entity c0
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_status c1 ON (c1.product_id = c0.entity_id)
INNER JOIN catalog_product_index_price c2 ON (c2.entity_id = c0.entity_id)
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal c3 ON (c3.entity_id = c0.entity_id AND c3.attribute_id=249)
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal c4 ON (c4.entity_id = c0.entity_id AND c4.attribute_id=251)
```

Após utilize o aliás antes de cada campo do select também.

Comment: Funcionou, apenas tive que adicionar o alias na parte do select. Obrigado, Emir.

Answer (score -2):

Bom dia, alguem pode me dar uma luz

Tenho essa **query** abaixo:

```
SELECT bairro.ba_bairro AS ba_bairro, count(cadastro.ca_bairro) AS 
count_ca_outro_bairro, sum(cadastro.ca_bairro) AS sum_ca_bairro FROM 
(cadastro LEFT JOIN bairro ON bairro.ba_codigo=cadastro.ca_bairro) GROUP BY bairro.ba_bairro
```

E faço uma **mysql_fetch_assoc()** mostrando o nome do bairro x e o total de registro dele na tabela cadastro.

Sendo que o mesmo existe mas 10 campos chamados:

```
ca_outro_bairro_1,ca_outro_bairro_2,ca_outro_bairro_3,ca_outro_bairro_4,ca_outro_bairro_5,ca_outro_bairro_6,ca_outro_bairro_7,ca_outro_bairro_8,ca_outro_bairro_9,ca_outro_bairro_10
```

Eu queria somar todos pois um cadastro pode morar no bairro x mas tem conhecido no bairro y.

**Quero ter um relatório aonde mostra o total por bairro que some o total de cadastro nessas colunas relacionadas acima**

**Exemplo:**
O bairro : bairro "centro" existe 20 cadastro na coluna `ca_bairro` e na coluna `ca_outro_bairro_1` tem 10 registro então no bairro centro vai mostra 30 registro e assim com as outras colunas.

Comment: Olá @Radio Itacity. Bem vindo ao **StackOverflow PT**. A sua resposta não fornece informação para solucionar o problema colocado. Aconselho a que remova a resposta e coloque a questão de forma adequada. Aproveite para fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para perceber melhor como funciona o site.